# Warning: require_once(controllers/booksController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un CRUD con php, con estilo o de manera con MVC, la cuestión es que quiero usar un layout para no volver a hacer HTML a cada rato, sino que es más fácil llamar a ese archivo con las etiquetas ya puestas...
***Bueno!, la cuestión es que me aparece este error***
Warning: require_once(controllers/booksController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPpuro\MVC\views\viewRegisters.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'controllers/booksController.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPpuro\MVC\views\viewRegisters.php on line 2

*He intentado de todo pero parece que al llamar a ese archivo guardado en una carpeta no lo llama o me sale el error* **(usé require_once("controllers/booksController.php");) donde ya tengo y obetengo los datos de la base de datos... El problema que cuando lo llamo del index no (Ver registro)** Me sale este error que puse

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: el error esta indicando que la ruta del `require_once` no permite encontrar el archivo... te recomiendo usar esto: https://github.com/arcanisgk/BEH-Basic-Error-Handler y https://github.com/arcanisgk/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun dicta modelo MVC,  en tu directorio raiz (MVC en tu caso) debes tener al menos 3 carpetas: models, views, controllers.
me imagino que las tienes de esa manera, asi que si estas en el directorio "views"  y quieres incluir un archivo del directorio "controllers" deberias subir un nivel atras (arriba) es decir usar "../"

asi que si quieres incluir al archivo booksController.php desde el archivo viewRegisters.php deberias ser asi:

```
require_once '../controllers/bookController.php';
```

No hay garantia que te funcione, es por eso que deberias usar rutas absolutas cuando quieres incluir un archivo en tu script, especialmente en un layout porque en cada archivo el directorio va a cambiar.

Y para las clases deberias cargarlas automaticamente con psr-4 o algun otro cargador automatico, o si quieres hacerlo tu podrias usar la funcion spl_autoload_register();

Cuando trabajas en arquitectura MVC lo mas recomendable es usar un inicializador, es decir un archivo `init.php` y en ese archivo configurar y llamar a las rutas, configuraciones, cargar las clases, etc. y luego incluir ese archivo init.php en tu index o en tu layout una sola vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias!... Pude darme cuenta que para que funcione, debo llamarlo desde el archivo index.php a todo. Obviamente lo estoy haciendo con php puro o nativo, muy diferente a laravel